# Segmentation fault keeps occurring at seemingly random variants of either number of threads or dimension of matrices being multiplied

Tags: c, multithreading, matrix, pthreads, mutex

I'm trying to write two programs that compute the norm of the product of two nxn dense matrices. The first section, Variant 1 works as intended. It parallel multiplies the two matrices together and then it computes the norm. Variant 2 doesn't work as expected. Here I tried to partition one matrix horizontally and multiply this with the other matrix. The multiplication works but for whatever reason I keep getting the following error when I go to compute the norm:

```
a(72157,0x110d5fdc0) malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x7f8b035060e8: probably modified after being freed.
Corrupt value: 0x40ab000000000000
a(72157,0x110d5fdc0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

Or

```
[2]    73373 segmentation fault  ./a 100 100
```

I thought that this perhaps could be the case of not freeing memory correctly but I freed the memory the threads were using and then allocated the memory again but I keep getting that error for dimensions that are seemingly greater than 5 at least. When I enter smaller matrices where the two command line arguments are the matrix size and number of threads, I get the following:

```
gcc -o a a.c -pthread && ./a 2 2
 ********** Variant 1 **********
 4.00  4.00
 4.00  4.00
 Norm : 8.00  Time Elapsed for Variant 1: 0.00

 ******************************
 ********** Variant 2 **********
 4.00  4.00
 4.00  4.00
Norm : 8.00 %


********** Variant 1 **********
 8.00  8.00  8.00  8.00
 8.00  8.00  8.00  8.00
 8.00  8.00  8.00  8.00
 8.00  8.00  8.00  8.00
 Norm : 32.00  Time Elapsed for Variant 1: 0.00

 ******************************
 ********** Variant 2 **********
 8.00  8.00  8.00  8.00
 8.00  8.00  8.00  8.00
 8.00  8.00  8.00  8.00
 8.00  8.00  8.00  8.00
Norm : 32.00 %
```

I genuinely don't know what's causing the problem. It could be the fact I'm reusing the code for computing the norm but that doesn't make sense to me as it's just a function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

// Declaring : Matrix Dimension, Number Of Threads, Norm, Matrices, Mutex
int n, num_threads;
double norm;
double * x, * y, * z;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void * computeNorm(void *arg){

        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

        int tid = *(int*)(arg);

        double sum = 0.0;

        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                sum += z[j * n + tid];
        }

        if(norm < sum){
                norm = sum;
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

        pthread_exit(NULL);

}

void * Parallel_Matrix_Multiplication(void *arg){

  pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

  int tid = *(int *)(arg);
  int partition = n / num_threads;
  int row_start = tid * partition;
  int row_end = (tid+1) * partition;

  for (int i = row_start; i < row_end; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j){
      for (int k = 0; k < n; ++k) {
    z[i * n + j] += x[ i * n + k ] * y[ k * n + j ];
      }
    }
  }

  pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void * Variant_2(void *arg){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        int tid = *(int*)(arg);
        int partition = n / num_threads;
        int row_start = tid * partition * n;
        int row_end = ((tid + 1) * partition) * n;

        for(int i = row_start; i < row_end; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                        for(int k = 0; k < n; k++){
                                z[i * n + j] += x[i * n + k] * y[k * n + j];
                        }
                }
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        pthread_exit(NULL);

}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
  int i;
  pthread_t * threads;
  pthread_t * norm_threads;

  pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

  n = atoi( argv[1] );
  num_threads = atoi( argv[2] );

  threads = (pthread_t *)malloc(num_threads * sizeof(pthread_t));


  x = malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));
  y = malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));
  z = malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));

  for(int i = 0; i < n * n; i++){
          x[i] = 1.0;
          y[i] = 2.0;
          z[i] = 0.0;
  }

  printf(" ********** Variant 1 ********** \n");
  for ( i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i ) {
    int *tid;
    tid = (int *) malloc( sizeof(int) );
    *tid = i;
    pthread_create( &threads[i], NULL, Parallel_Matrix_Multiplication, (void *)tid );
  }

  for ( i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i ) {
    pthread_join( threads[i], NULL );
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                    printf(" %0.2f ", z[i * n + j]);
            }
            printf("\n");
    }

  norm_threads = (pthread_t*)malloc(num_threads * sizeof(pthread_t));
  for(int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++){
        int *tid;
        tid = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        *tid = i;
        pthread_create(&norm_threads[i], NULL, computeNorm, (void*)tid);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < num_threads; i++){
          pthread_join(norm_threads[i], NULL);
  }


  printf(" Norm : %0.2f ", norm);

  printf("\n ******************************");

  norm = 0.0;
  for(int i = 0; i < n * n; i++){ z[i] = 0.0; }
 
  free(threads);
  free(norm_threads);
  threads= (pthread_t*)malloc(num_threads * sizeof(pthread_t));
  norm_threads = (pthread_t*)malloc(num_threads * sizeof(pthread_t));

  printf("\n ********** Variant 2 ********** \n");

  for(i = 0; i < num_threads; i++){
          int *tid;
          tid = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
          *tid = i;
          pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, Variant_2, (void*)tid);
  }

  for(i =0; i < num_threads; i++){
          pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
  }

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
          for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                  printf(" %0.2f ", z[i * n + j]);
          }
          printf("\n");
  }


  for(i = 0; i < num_threads; i++){
          int *tid;
          tid = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
          *tid = i;
          pthread_create(&norm_threads[i], NULL, computeNorm, (void*)tid);
  }

  for(i = 0; i < num_threads; i++){
          pthread_join(norm_threads[i], NULL);
  }

  printf("Norm : %0.2f ", norm);
 
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);



  return 0;
}
```

VALGRIND OUTPUT - GCC

```
==66355== Thread 3:
==66355== Invalid read of size 8
==66355==    at 0x1000015D7: Variant_2 (in ./a)
==66355==    by 0x100612108: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x10060DB8A: thread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==66355==  Address 0x100882ac0 is 0 bytes after a block of size 80,000 alloc'd
==66355==    at 0x100111635: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-6049595/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==66355==    by 0x100001B4C: main (in ./a)
==66355==
==66355== Invalid read of size 8
==66355==    at 0x100001600: Variant_2 (in ./a)
==66355==    by 0x100612108: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x10060DB8A: thread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==66355==  Address 0x10084a350 is 0 bytes after a block of size 80,000 alloc'd
==66355==    at 0x100111635: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-6049595/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==66355==    by 0x100001738: main (in ./a)
==66355==
==66355== Invalid write of size 8
==66355==    at 0x100001605: Variant_2 (in ./a)
==66355==    by 0x100612108: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x10060DB8A: thread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==66355==  Address 0x10084a350 is 0 bytes after a block of size 80,000 alloc'd
==66355==    at 0x100111635: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-6049595/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==66355==    by 0x100001738: main (in ./a)
==66355==
==66355==
==66355== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==66355==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x100DC6540
==66355==    at 0x1000015D7: Variant_2 (in ./a)
==66355==    by 0x100612108: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x10060DB8A: thread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==66355==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==66355==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==66355==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==66355==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==66355==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
--66355:0:schedule VG_(sema_down): read returned -4
--66355:0:schedule VG_(sema_down): read returned -4
==66355==
==66355== HEAP SUMMARY:
==66355==     in use at exit: 282,462 bytes in 494 blocks
==66355==   total heap usage: 538 allocs, 44 frees, 552,158 bytes allocated
==66355==
==66355== Thread 1:
==66355== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 20 of 75
==66355==    at 0x100111C90: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-6049595/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==66355==    by 0x1006E65F3: objc::DenseMap<objc_class*, objc_class*, objc::DenseMapValueInfo<objc_class*>, objc::DenseMapInfo<objc_class*>, objc::detail::DenseMapPair<objc_class*, objc_class*> >::grow(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1006E64BA: addRemappedClass(objc_class*, objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1006D6C43: allocateBuckets(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1006D6398: lookUpImpOrForward (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x100672F99: _xpc_payload_alloc (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x100672E65: _xpc_payload_create_from_mach_msg (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x100672D22: xpc_receive_mach_msg (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x10068CB8A: _xpc_pipe_routine (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x100671B61: xpc_pipe_routine_with_flags (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1006719E1: _xpc_interface_routine (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x100673CE7: bootstrap_look_up3 (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==66355==
==66355== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 21 of 75
==66355==    at 0x100111C90: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-6049595/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==66355==    by 0x1006E65F3: objc::DenseMap<objc_class*, objc_class*, objc::DenseMapValueInfo<objc_class*>, objc::DenseMapInfo<objc_class*>, objc::detail::DenseMapPair<objc_class*, objc_class*> >::grow(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1006E64BA: addRemappedClass(objc_class*, objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1006E5FF3: realizeClassWithoutSwift(objc_class*, objc_class*) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1006D6D44: -[NSObject dealloc] (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1006D6398: lookUpImpOrForward (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x100672F99: _xpc_payload_alloc (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x100672E65: _xpc_payload_create_from_mach_msg (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x100672D22: xpc_receive_mach_msg (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x10068CB8A: _xpc_pipe_routine (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x100671B61: xpc_pipe_routine_with_flags (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1006719E1: _xpc_interface_routine (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==66355==
==66355== 56 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 26 of 75
==66355==    at 0x100111C90: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-6049595/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==66355==    by 0x10058A190: _notify_fork_child (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x10058A3A0: _notify_fork_child (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x100584A6B: notify_register_check (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1003BC9ED: notify_register_tz (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1003BC35F: tzsetwall_basic (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1003BE130: localtime (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x10037C923: gettimeofday (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1000017D0: main (in ./a)
==66355==
==66355== 112 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 44 of 75
==66355==    at 0x100111C90: calloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-6049595/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==66355==    by 0x10058A3CC: _notify_fork_child (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x100584A6B: notify_register_check (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1003BC9ED: notify_register_tz (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1003BC35F: tzsetwall_basic (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1003BE130: localtime (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x10037C923: gettimeofday (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==66355==    by 0x1000017D0: main (in ./a)
==66355==
==66355== 396 bytes in 99 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 58 of 75
==66355==    at 0x100111635: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-6049595/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==66355==    by 0x100001807: main (in ./a)
==66355==
==66355== 396 bytes in 99 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 59 of 75
==66355==    at 0x100111635: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-6049595/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==66355==    by 0x10000195E: main (in ./a)
==66355==
==66355== 800 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 63 of 75
==66355==    at 0x100111635: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-6049595/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==66355==    by 0x1000016CF: main (in ./a)
==66355==
==66355== 800 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 64 of 75
==66355==    at 0x100111635: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/HEAD-6049595/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==66355==    by 0x100001937: main (in ./a)
==66355==
==66355== LEAK SUMMARY:
==66355==    definitely lost: 2,392 bytes in 200 blocks
==66355==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==66355==      possibly lost: 232 bytes in 4 blocks
==66355==    still reachable: 261,764 bytes in 127 blocks
==66355==                       of which reachable via heuristic:
==66355==                         newarray           : 56 bytes in 1 blocks
==66355==         suppressed: 18,074 bytes in 163 blocks
==66355== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==66355== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==66355==
==66355== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==66355== ERROR SUMMARY: 1542409 errors from 11 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 13)
[2]    66355 segmentation fault  valgrind --leak-check=yes ./a 100 100
```

Comment: Wild guess: did you try what happens if you only create one single thread? Where is `variant_1`?

Comment: Where do you free x, y and z?

Comment: @Jabberwocky The error still persists with one thread. My apologies, the function Parallel_Matrix_Multiplication is variant 1

Comment: @Lundin I didn't but I just checked it there by freeing them then allocating memory again and it still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: if the server has `gdb` (an excellent debugger) then can debug your program remotely because `gdb` can be run remotely

Comment: @user253751 I updated the Valgrind output. It seems that the problem comes from the Variant 2 function

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile!  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.   ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results

Comment: @user3629249 The code does compile, try this? gcc -o FOO FOO.c -pthread

Comment: @user3629249 The error that arises using those flags is : `implicit conversion changes signedness`

Comment: the point is that with `z[i * n + j] += x[i * n + k] * y[k * n + j];` somehow `i * n + j` or `i * n + k` or `k * n + j` is too big. Can you figure out why?

Comment: OT:  regarding statements like: `threads= (pthread_t*)malloc(num_threads * sizeof(pthread_t));`  1) in C, the return type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Suggest removing that `cast`.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful,  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "malloc failed" ); cleanup, then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`  The call to `perror()` will output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: @user253751 I'm going to assume that `n` is the problem. I suppose is it because that when I multiply the indices by `nn`, I go outside of the partition that I have to be in?

Comment: @JiangShi,  adding the `-pthread` parameter  only comes into significance during the `linking` of the code.  My comment was a problem during the `compile` step.

Comment: @JiangShi, Note: when a warning message is output by the compiler, that means the compiler 'guessed' as to what the programmer wanted to do and inserted some code.  That does NOT mean that the inserted code is correct.

Comment: you could make your program do the checking for you. If i\*n+j is bigger than 9999, then print out n. and print out i. and print out j. and print out i\*n+j. and this might help you figure out what went wrong

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding (the compiler does not care) Please use meaningful variable names.  Names like `n` and `z` are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: OT: regarding; `n = atoi( argv[1] );
  num_threads = atoi( argv[2] );`  always check `argc` to assure the user actually entered the two(2) parameters before accessing beyond `argv[0]`.  If the parameters are missing,  then output a `USAGE` message to `stderr` and exit the program.  Also, the function: `atoi()` does not tell the program when it fails.  Suggest using: `strtol()`

Comment: @user253751 It seems that I'm going far out of the range. I tried printing out the values you suggested sans the if statement for a 2x2 matrix and it seems the indices go up to 7! `i*n+j:[7] i:[3] j[1] n[2]` was the last statement that was printed.

Comment: @user3629249 The argc was something I was going to include once I finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Valgrind output is telling you that your `Variant_2()` function is overrunning the bounds of allocated memory.  It is doing so because these bounds computations are wrong:

> ```
>         int row_start = tid * partition * n;
>         int row_end = ((tid + 1) * partition) * n;
> ```

At that point, the `partition` variable contains the computed number of rows in a partition, `n` is the total number of rows (and of columns), and `tid` is an integer thread index.  To divide the rows among threads in contiguous blocks, each thread should start at row `tid * partition`, and end before the next thread's first row, `(tid + 1) * partition`.  The additional factors of `n` are inappropriate for row-number computations.

You do need that factor of `n` when computing element offsets within the 1D work arrays, but you already provide it:

> ```
>                                 z[i * n + j] += x[i * n + k] * y[k * n + j];
> ```

---

Note also that your approach to partitioning the rows works only if the number of threads evenly divides the number of rows.  Otherwise, one or more of the last rows will not be assigned to any thread.